# $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on the set of norms on $X$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a vetor space. Prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on the set of norms on $X$.

Where $\sim $ is the equivalence of two norms.

This seems very abstract. What exactly do I have to prove.

For reflexive, if we have $x \in X$ so $a||x|| \leq |||x||| \leq b||x||$ for some $a,b >0$ which seems obvious as there must exist some values of $a,b$ to satisfy this.

Symmetric: No idea.

Transitive: Not sure. Normally something gets mapped to something but nothing is being mapped here.

Comment: How is $\sim$ defined?

Comment: I think its when two norms are equivalent. So $a||.|| \leq |||.||| \leq b||.||$

Comment: I can't believe  that what bothers you is really this abstract. The way that I read your question right no, is, what are (all) the possible equivalence relations for the set of norms on a vector space X. While this would be a very interesting question (to me), I don't think that this is what you intend to ask. Do you have some topology in mind? Are you asking what norms induce the same topology?

Comment: To put it to the extreme case: let $N$ be the set of norms over $X$, then a equivalence relation could be any subset of $N\times N$ that satisfies reflexivity, translation and symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is semantic, because the definition of "equivalent norms" is not phrased as an equivalence relation, but as an order relation.  The exercises wants you to check that in fact it is an equivalence.

reflexive: $||.||\sim||.||$ by taking $a,b=1$.

symmetric: $||.||\sim|||.|||\Rightarrow|||.|||\sim||.||$ by exchanging taking $1/b$ and $1/a$ for the bounds

you should now figure out the transitive...

Comment: Could you elaborate on symmetric please

Comment: $$a\|v\|\leq|||v|||\leq b\|v\|\Leftrightarrow\frac1b|||v|||\leq\|v\|\leq\frac1a|||v|||$$